# How to compile c# file to .wasm file?

Tags: mono, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor, .net-6.0

I know that there are same questions asked by other people in the past, and the answer is no. But with the .net 6 realsed, blazor webassembly now supports AOT compiling, the problem is that the output is bundled in a big "dotnet.wasm" file, which contains the dotnet runtime as well as my app code(please tell me if my understanding is wrong?). so my questions is, how can I compile any c# file to a separeted .wasm file?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this in any way related to Blazor? Your question is "how can I compile any c# file to a separated .wasm file" - which doesn't seem Blazor specific.

Comment: it does since blazor currently is able to compile c# to .wasm with the new AOT compiler, the only problem is the output is in one single dotnet.wasm. what I need is to be able to compile c# files into seperated .wasm files.

Comment: Nope, one file only at this time.

Comment: Does the OP means that he want to compile c# to wasm in such a way that the app front-end runs without the need for the .net runtime?

Comment: Did you find any solution? Any update?